# ComboBoxColumn errors out when trying to load data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to create a DataGridView with a DataGridViewComboBox
I am using the following code to generate it using 2 function that return DataTables for populating it:

```
 '// Returns a DataTable with 2 Columns of Type Integer and System.String
 '// Column 1 are IDs called ID, Column 2 is a String of numbers called CompanyCode
 '// Example: 
 '// 1,'9999'
 '// 2,'9998'
 '// 3,'9997' etc.
 Dim uTableSys As DataTable = GetCompanyCodeLinks()

 '// Returns a DataTable with 1 Column of Type System.String
 '// The Column is called CC
 '// Example: '0001','0002','1234'
 Dim CompanyCodes As DataTable = GetListCompanyCodes()

 Dim uBindSys As New BindingSource
 uBindSys.DataSource = uTableSys

 Dim uCol1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
 uCol1.HeaderText = "Buchungskreis"

 '// Points to uTableSys.CompanyCode
 uCol1.DataPropertyName = "CompanyCode"

 uCol1.DataSource = CompanyCodes
 uCol1.ValueType = uTableSys.Columns(1).DataType

 '// Points to CompanyCodes.CC
 uCol1.ValueMember = "CC"

 uCol1.DisplayMember = uCol1.ValueMember
 Me.DGV.Columns.Add(uCol1)

 Me.DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = False
 Me.DGV.DataSource = uBindSys
```

But as soon as I add `uCol1.DataPropertyName = "CompanyCode"`, which I assume would link the DGV Column to the BindingSource table "CompanyCode" column, it returns with the following error:

`"The DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid"`

I have checked the types of the DataTable, which are System.String, which the Column is set to via the `uCol1.ValueType` in the code. For clarification, `uTableSys.Columns(1).DataType` returns `System.String`

So why does it return with a "value is not valid" error?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue:
The value that is written in the cell from the GridView DataSource on loading has to exist ComboBox list as well. If the value does not exist, it will throw the error.